# method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, exception, android-studio, nullpointerexception

When I try to run this, the emulator crashes and I get this Exception

> method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception

Here is my code, I know the error is in the last line but I don't know how to fix it

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        // FIXME: Experimenting

        try {

            ReadingFactory parser = new BOMFactory();
            WeatherService s = new WeatherService(
                    "BOM", "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60801/IDV60801.94839.json", parser
            );

            s.run();

         //   Thread test = new Thread(s);
           // test.start();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BOMResponse bomResponse = new BOMResponse();
        TextView temperature  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperature);
        temperature.setText(String.format("%d", bomResponse.getObservations().getData().get(0).getAirTemp().toString()));

    }
}
```

Here is my complete Stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                    
Process: com.example.teamredrmit.weatherapp, PID: 1792                                                                   
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.teamredrmit.weatherapp/com.example.teamredrmit.weathe
app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.example.teamredrmit.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add your complete stacktrace.

Comment: @PrerakSola I added the Stacktrace

Comment: @PrerakSola I think it's this line


`temperature.setText(String.format("%d", bomResponse.getObservations().getData().get(0).getAirTemp().toString()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 BOMResponse bomResponse = new BOMResponse();
        TextView temperature  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperature);
        temperature.setText(String.format("%d", bomResponse.getObservations().getData().get(0).getAirTemp().toString()));
```

here you are just initializing your `BOMResponse` object . you are not setting value inside your custom object so  `bomResponse.getObservations()` will be `null`.  you have to set value first then use it.